# Send push messagefrom PHP server on localhost to client on android

Tags: php, android, push-notification, client-server, intranet

We are facing issue with push notification kind of feature in intranet.
we have PHP web server on localhost and client on android application.

We want to keep all devices updated even if there is update form any device.
here we can update server from client using web service but what about server to client notification.

We are using intranet only not internet so is there any push notification facility for such scenario. Because server needs to send update on all android devices if there is any change

Comment: what is the issue actually?

Comment: We are using intranet only not internet so is there any push notification facility for such scenario. Because server needs  to send update on all android devices if there is any change

Comment: you may want to provide some code to narrow down the question and make the problem more clear.

Comment: Your idea is good, but i don't think that'l be possible. May be you can use a `TCP socket`